# Как работает функция — обертка в этом случаи?

Tags: javascript

Дело в том, что когда пытаются обратиться к примитиву как к объекту, то он оборачивается в свою функцию - обертку, и в следствии получает объект, у которого и будет вызывать свойство или метод, но мне не понятно почему работает именно так:

```
"12".valueOf();
"12"

12.valueOf();
VM1160:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

(12).valueOf();
12

12..valueOf();
12
```

Не могу понять почему не работает ( **12.valueOf();** ) пример, и почему срабатывает ( **12..valueOf();** ).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Точка, идущая сразу за цифрой в числе считается десятичной точкой, а не обращением к свойству. Чтобы этого избежать, можно например использовать пробел:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Dot_notation

```
12 .toString(); // '12'
```